# Find a point on a line perpendicular and through the middle of another line

Tags: matlab, vector, 3d, computational-geometry, angle

In the diagram below

- all points are in 3D space (x, y, z) **and in the same plane**
- BC defines a vector with midpoint A
- PA should be perpendicular to BC, **however I do not know how to find P**
- I need to determine the angle between OA and PA

Do you know how this can be solved? Glad to provide additional info if needed.

[image]

Comment: I suppose all of them lie in the same plane.

Comment: they may not be in the same plane, they could be in different planes along 3D space

Comment: Then the problem is not well defined. As `P` rotates around the axis `BC` the angle `PAO` will change.

Comment: you're correct, I'll edit the OP to state they're all in the same plane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple use of the cross-product and scalar-product:

You first find a normal vector `N` of the plane spanned by those points. This is done via the cross product of `B-A` and `O-A`.
Then the directional vector `AP` can be found as the cross product of `N` and `B-A`. For finding the angle we take the scalar product of the normalized vectors `AP` and `AO`, apply `acos` and convert to degrees.

```
%// Example data
A = [0,0,0];
B = [-1,0,0];
C = [1,0,0];
O = [-1,-1,0];
%// Computation
normalize = @(X) X/norm(X);
N = normalize(cross(B-A,O-A));
AP = cross(N,B-A);
phi = (180/pi)*acos(dot(normalize(AP),normalize(O-A)))
```